# Accessing dependent files without sharing in condor

Tags: distributed, cluster-computing, hpc

I have 6 windows machine on which condor can run the jobs,
when I'm running the interdependent files(one file calling other file) on condor,I'm supposed to share(requires Administrative access,) the calling file to everyone on the machine where i'm running the jobs, and it is happens that the submitted file generates output which is placed in a text file and if I  re-submit the job to the condor i'm getting a error that "cannot Access file : permission denied" for the output file, so i had to change the output file name every time I re-submit the jobs to the condor.

My Submit file looks like this

## test_job.sub

#
universe = vanilla
Executable = C:\Progra~2\R\R-2.10.1\bin\Rscript.exe
arguments =  One.R
getenv = true

## requirements = ARCH == "INTEL" && OPSYS == "WINNT60"

input = One.R

should_transfer_files = YES
when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT
transfer_input_files = Two.R
transfer_executable = false

Output = test_r_out.out
Log = test_r_log.log
error = test_r.error

queue

One.R calls Two.R

My problem is everyone who runs their jobs on this machine should be able to directly access the dependent files without the option of manual sharing and changing the output filenames.

Appreciate any ideas on this

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to try the email list condor-users@cs.wisc.edu, where many condor folks hang out.

Second, your first sentence is mighty long, so I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

If you need the output filenames to be distinct for each condor run, you can simply name them with the condor cluster id appended to the filename.  Just change

Output = test_r_out.out

to

Output = test_r_out.out.$(Cluster)